# Trying to clean up my MBR's

Tags: grub2, uninstall, mbr

I curently have at least two Grub's installed on my HD.
Iḿ trying to use a couple of tools to configure the one currently in use (I guess that is the one on /dev/sda).

More precise, I want to load some Live-CD .iso files using grml-rescueboot.

To cut an even longer story short, I really only need one Grub installed so all the tools hook up to this one automatically (I hope?) e.g. delete, remove, annihilate the rest.

I made a Boot info dump here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6734499/ for anyone willing to take a look and help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Jay Bart Cornelisse

Comment: This will not affect performance in any way, it just means you could change your bios boot order and be fine, this is a case of not-broke-don't-fix-it and the current way is not slow. Do you /need/ to do this?

Comment: You only have one drive with one MBR, so that is what you really boot from. All the others are in PBRs or partition boot sectors which grub does not normally use and is not recommended with grub2. But otherwise PBR is not used, so I would not attempt to zero them out.

Comment: Roger that, its just im fooling around with this old laptop, fiddling with all kinds of linux builds and familiarizing myself wit linux in general. i ll probably be better of somehow pointing the grml-rescueboot to the proper grub. as I take it deleting grub is not that easy or without danger?

Comment: ANyways, thanks for thinking out loud. I will try and find a way to configure the right grub manually instead.